# why Ajax Request Change Parameter Value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new in web.I am using ajax request to update some values.I am sending a url in parameter.but that i send , i don't get that.I dont know what am i missing here.Can some one help me in this.I send the following url in parameter.

https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mebel-perof.ru%2Fkresla%2Fstaff

but i get following values  when I recieve this.I am not sure what am i missing to send request.

https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.mebel-perof.ru/kresla/staff

I have tried both

```
  $_REQUEST['page_url'] 
  $_POST['page_url']
```

See my Following Code:

```
var url_api = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mebel-perof.ru%2Fkresla%2Fstaff";

var req_url = global_domain_ws+'/actiongoogleplus.php';
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : req_url,
        data :"page_url="+url_api,
        success : function(a) {

            location.reload(true);
        }
    });
```

Some can help me in this what m i missing here . I don't know.
thanks

Comment: You have a typo in "url_aoi" declaration, should be "url_api"....

Comment: this topic is helpful, maybe it will solve your problem, [this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613452/why-ajax-request-change-parameter-value

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in "url_aoi" declaration, should be "url_api"

**EDIT**

Look this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : req_url,
    data : {'page_url':url_api},
    success : function(a) {

        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Note the data is sent as object, so that way $_POST should work!!!

**EDIT 2**

Are you using jQuery, if so then replace $.ajax with:

```
$.post(
    req_url, 
    {'page_url':url_api},
    function(a){
        location.reload(true);
    });
```

Also i have edited my previous edit, too weird you say it is not working, as i do a lot of ajax that way.

Comment: If you pass the string appended, note the original "url_api" also has "=" there, so the parameter passes malformed...